# android "achartengine" y-axis data difference

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using "achartengine" for time-chart and I want to change data on y-axis from 1,2,3 to 0.5,1.0,1.5 etc
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own custom labels.

```
renderer.addYTextLabel(1, "0.5");
```

In order to disable the default labels do this:

```
renderer.setYLabels(0);
```